# Closing addon window when FireFox is closed automatically

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I developed a Firefox add-on, that is placed on the bottom of FireFox (Like firebug). When advanced search button of it is clicked a popup will be opened, but when FireFox is closed by user the pop-up remained open. How can I change it so when firefox is closed it also be closed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just need to be given `depended` feature.